# HttpServletRequest returns NULL in a custom jaas module when use https, why?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, jaas

I need to get ip client in a custom jaas module, when run over http this code works, but if run over https this code return `null`:

```java
String ipClient="";
        try {


            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)PolicyContext.getContext("javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest");
            if(request != null)
                ipClient = getClientIpAddr(request);

        }catch(UnknownHostException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getLogger(SecurityUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (PolicyContextException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Logger.getLogger(SecurityUtil.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


public static String getClientIpAddr(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String ip = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");

    if (ip == null || ip.length() == 0 || "unknown".equalsIgnoreCase(ip)) {
        ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
    }
    return ip;
}
```

Comment: provide more details

Comment: Please show your deployment descriptor along with where are you tring to get this line working?

Comment: (also, when asking a newcomer to provide more details, it's useful to help them out by letting them know what we want...). "What have you tried?", "How are you detecting null", "Is this the smallest reproducable bit of code?" etc.